# How to make an anonymous array as a field in a structure type definition?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, padding, typedef

IDE:       Code Composer IDE Version 12.
COMPILER:  ti-cgt-arm_20.2.6.LTS
CHIP:      Texas Instruments AM6442 (ARM Cortex R5F core).
LANGUAGE:  C

I am writing some structure typedefs that define the layout in memory for some hardware registers.  In the memory map for some peripheral modules there may be relatively large gaps in the memory (like 1024 bytes).  Some of these peripherals are quite complex (like 500+ unique register names with various padding areas).  All the registers are 32-bit aligned, and 32-bits long.  To account for these gaps, I put arrays of uint32_t as padding.

Right now, the padding arrays have names.  But since there is no situation where I need to access the memory in the padding areas (it would probably trigger a memory fault), I would like the padding to be anonymous.

Using anonymous padding has the advantage of not cluttering up the code completion popup menus in the IDE.  In those menus I just want to see my register names, not all the names of the padding areas.

```
   //Example
   typdef struct __attribute__((packed)){
      uint32_t REG1;
      uint32_t REG2;
      uint32_t REG3;
      uint32_t REG4;
      uint32_t PAD_1[64];
      uint32_t REG5;
      uint32_t REG6;
      uint32_t PAD_2[32];
      uint32_t REG7;
    }
```

**Is there a way to make the padding arrays anonymous?**.  Anonymous arrays exists as compound literals, but I don't know of a syntax to do it in a type definition.  I would like to avoid solutions like putting 1000 anonymous uint32_t in the struct.

Comment: @user4574, An approach is to use `__LINE__` to form the name for the "anonymous" member.   It will still have a name yet not one code will likely discern. Of course this does not meet the "not cluttering up the code completion popup", but maybe something like `ZZZ#` to put it at the end of the (usually A-Z sorted) completion list.  Me, I just favor `ZZZpad1, ZZZpad2,  ...`

Comment: @Fe2O3 As TI is mentioned as chip vendor, using these large padding arrays just follows the style TI uses in provided headers. They also use large `RESERVED*` arrays. (At least in the headers for MSPM0 which I use) I think, there is nothing wrong in sticking to a consistent style through the whole project.

Comment: @Gerhardh I yield to your knowledge of TI practices. Deleted my comment (based on the impression that this was simply something the OP cooked up.) Thanks for the information.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You must name struct members. The convention for register maps is to name things `reserved0`, `reserved1` and so on. If you can't accept that for strange IDE reasons, then I suppose you have to make several structs instead. Although it is always a bad idea to rewrite the source to suit peculiar tastes of programmers/IDEs, rather than having the programmer/IDE adapt to reality...

As mentioned in comments by @chux, it might be a good idea to create automatic, self-increasing numbers by appending `__LINE__`:

```
#define CONCAT(x,y) x ## y
#define reserved(x) CONCAT(reserved_, x)

typedef struct
{
  uint32_t x;
  uint32_t reserved(__LINE__);
  uint32_t reserved(__LINE__);
} struct_t;
```

Which will boil down to something like:

```
uint32_t reserved_7;
uint32_t reserved_8;
```

You can indeed toss in a 'z' to move all register names at the end of the code completion list, `CONCAT(zreserved_, x)` etc.

You can also use these macros to declare arrays: `uint32_t reserved(__LINE__) [10];` will yield something like:

```
uint32_t reserved_8 [10];
```

---

Also please note that using `__attribute__((packed))` in a register map struct is very fishy - automatic struct padding should never occur here. The correct approach to guard against that is to use `static_assert`.

```
static_assert(sizeof(mystruct) == expected, "Incorrect struct padding detected in mystruct.")
```

Comment: Please note that the problem with the code completion menus being cluttered up by the reserved bits is not unique to Code Composer.  I have used dozens of IDEs and I believe all of them would have this same problem unless there is a way to make the unused bits anonymous, or some (probably nonstandard IDE specific) way to mark them to not show up.